# How can I automate Python to help me download things from a database (Filemaker)?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, automation, filemaker

I want to automate some boring works with Python.

I need to download data from Filemaker from time to time.
I don't want to manually click through all the buttons on Filemaker (to open the database, search, select download as a particular format..etc)

Can I accomplish this with a few Python codes?

I'm using Mac OSX, Python 3 and Filemaker.

Comment: This looks possible with [PyFileMaker](https://github.com/aeguana/PyFileMaker), see examples [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyfilemaker/)

Comment: You can open FileMaker with a fmp:// URL: http://www.filemaker.com/help/12/fmp/en/html/sharing_data.16.7.html  In that URL you can specify a script that can perform all the steps you want, the script can also close FileMaker if you don't want it to stay open.  That is an alternative to setting up FileMaker-Python integration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For quite a few things you specifically mention, are you aware that a FileMaker script could do this?

If you really want to do this with Python, I've written a free FileMaker plug-in (http://beezwax.net/bbox) that provides tight Python integration with FileMaker. In your Python script you can then use the `fm.executesql` function to query the FileMaker table and process the data however you'd like. macOS only however, and for your use case, probably makes the most sense if done client-side.

Still client-side (so file would have to already be open for this to work), you could use an ODBC connection + SQL to pull in your data to Python.

If the file is hosted on FileMaker Server, you have quite a few options, and I'll just list some of the options you might consider:

- setup an ODBC connection from Python to FileMaker, then use SQL to pull in data
- use pyFileMaker
- use FMS' XML API to get your data (https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/16/en/fms16_cwp_guide.pdf)
- use FMS' REST API (https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/16/en/restapi/)
- create a **system schedule** on FMS that will first run a simple script to export your data to the server's Documents folder as a tab/csv file, and then have the Python pick it up from there (http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/11893)

I wouldn't try scraping the data using FileMaker Server's WebDirect interface unless I really had to, but that is theoretically possible.

Comment: Hi @Simon, it's very interesting to see these different options! By the way, I just met Vince in Salzburg. I gave a presentation on accessing FileMaker data via ODBC with R.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple google feel-lucky result: [PyFileMaker](https://github.com/aeguana/PyFileMaker)

Despite that, it should also be easy to make a spider with [pyspider](http://docs.pyspider.org/en/latest/) and [WebDirect of Filemaker](https://www.filemaker.com/support/technologies/webdirect.html)